# Magento 2.3.0 How to display only product attribute in custom rule condition into the custom admin form using the ui component

Tags: adminform, ui-form, rules, magento2.3.0, catalog-rules

I have implement custom condition Rule to my custom module [Take refrance from this link](https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/) and it is working fine.

But it is display also other rule like **cart attribute**, **customer attribute**, **other attribute** display like below image

[image]

But i don't want other attributes list i just want only **product attribute** list display like below image.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!